# Dropdown menu hover overlap

Tags: html, css, menu

I have the below code:

HTML:

```
<nav id="NavBar">
        <ul>
            <li class="lvl0"><a href="#">[#Heading 1#]</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 1.1#]</a></li>
                    <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 1.2#]</a></li>
                    <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 1.3#]</a></li>
                    <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 1.4#]</a></li>
                    <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 1.5#]</a></li>
                    <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 1.6#]</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="lvl0" ><a href="#">[#Heading 2#]</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 2.1#]</a></li>
                    <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 2.2#]</a></li>
                    <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 2.3#]</a></li>
                    <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 2.4#]</a></li>
                    <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 2.5#]</a></li>
                    <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 2.6#]</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="lvl0" ><a href="#">[#Heading 3#]</a>
                <ul>
                    <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 3.1#]</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="lvl2" ><a href="#">[#link 3.1.1#]</a></li>
                            <li class="lvl2" ><a href="#">[#link 3.1.2#]</a></li>
                            <li class="lvl2" ><a href="#">[#link 3.1.3#]</a></li>
                            <li class="lvl2" ><a href="#">[#link 3.1.4#]</a></li>
                            <li class="lvl2" ><a href="#">[#link 3.1.5#]</a></li>
                            <li class="lvl2" ><a href="#">[#link 3.1.6#]</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                        <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 3.2#]</a></li>
                        <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 3.3#]</a></li>
                        <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 3.4#]</a></li>
                        <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 3.5#]</a></li>
                        <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 3.6#]</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="lvl0" ><a href="#">[#Heading 4#]</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 4.1#]</a></li>
                        <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 4.2#]</a></li>
                        <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 4.3#]</a></li>
                        <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 4.4#]</a></li>
                        <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 4.5#]</a></li>
                        <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 4.6#]</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="lvl0" ><a href="#">[#Heading 5#]</a>
                    <ul class="align-right">
                        <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 5.1#]</a></li>
                        <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 5.2#]</a></li>
                        <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 5.3#]</a></li>
                        <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 5.4#]</a></li>
                        <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 5.5#]</a></li>
                        <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 5.6#]</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="lvl0" ><a href="#">[#Heading 6#]</a>
                    <ul class="align-right">
                        <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 6.1#]</a></li>
                        <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 6.2#]</a></li>
                        <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 6.3#]</a></li>
                        <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 6.4#]</a></li>
                        <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 6.5#]</a></li>
                        <li class="lvl1" ><a href="#">[#link 6.6#]</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

CSS:

```
#NavBar {
    width: 1000px;
}

#NavBar *{
    list-style: none;
}

#NavBar ul li{
    float: left;
    padding: 7px 22px 12px;
    border-left: 1px dashed #dadada;
    position: relative;
}
#NavBar ul{
    padding: 0px;
}

#NavBar ul li ul{
    display: none;
    left: 0px;
    width: 403px;
    margin-top: 12px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(85,85,85,0.75);
    border-top: 1px dashed #dadada;
}

#NavBar ul li ul li{
    width: 143px;
    border: 0;
}

#NavBar ul li:hover > ul{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

#NavBar ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666;
}

#NavBar .align-right{
    left: auto;
    right: 0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/8TwbU/

The problem is that first i need to develop the menu in such a way that the section that opens on hover should open and take the entire width of the menu. Thus when i hover on any of the links, a common area should be there that opens up for displaying the menu content.

secondly the lvl2 class is overlapping on hover the already open content. thus ruining the look.

Also please suggest if i need to use jquery to solve this..currently i was looking for a solution without jquery.

Comment: Where are you wanting the lvl2 class items to appear? To the right of the lvl1 box?

Comment: actually i want the lvl2 box be shown as a simple list below lvl1 thus not being hidden and all...http://www.myntra.com/ menu is the one i wish to achieve...that the lvl0 forms menu names, lvl1 becomes title to subcategories and lvl2 becomes the narrower links

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion I can offer is to make `#NavBar a { display: block }` and cover the same space as it's parent `li` element, that way you can capture hover and clicks when navigating sub menus.

Since the `ul` showing absolutely, why not add a `background` and `z-index` to them?